# Splitting filenames for their first word in Python

Tags: python

I have 2 shapefiles, each one placed in a different folder:

- "C:\...\Folder O\Germany (O).shp"
- "C:\...\Folder P\Germany Berlin (P).shp"

The following script finds the shapefiles and contains a couple of `if` conditions. The first `if` condition strips the "(O).shp" and "(P).shp" from the shapefiles. This works perfectly.

I want to set up a second `if` condition whereby the **first** name of both shapefiles matches, so in this case it would be "Germany". I thought the [string.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) method would be ideal but I'm clearly not implementing it correctly.

Can you point out my mistake?

```
def run():
    for o in glob.glob("C:\Users\me\Desktop\Test\Folder O" + "\*.shp"):
        for p in glob.glob("C:\Users\me\Desktop\Test\Folder P" + "\*.shp"):
            if os.path.basename(o).rstrip("(O).shp") == os.path.basename(p).rstrip("(P).shp"):
                print p
                # works perfectly up to here

                if os.path.basename(o).split(o[[1]]) == os.path.basename(p).split(p[1]]):
                    print p
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if os.path.basename(o).split(' ')[0] == os.path.basename(p).split(' ')[0]:
    print p
```

This splits the basename where spaces (' ') occur, creating a list of string parts, and returns the item in the list at index 0 (the first item).

You would need to modify this to split at any other character (i.e. underscore, hyphen, etc)